# The program '[12604] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, iis-express, visual-studio-debugging

When running my solution in debug mode, IIS Express and Internet Explorer as the browser, I get the following error:

```
The program '[12604] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[12604] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.  If I change to Chrome, I do not get this.

The only way to resolve this and still use IISExpress and IE is to go into my properties of the web project and uncheck **Enable Edit and Continue** under Debuggers.

Any idea as to why?

Answer (score 13):

#### Try any of the following fixes....

1. **Clean + Rebuild Solution**
2. **Restart Visual Studio**
3. **Run Visual Studio as Admin**
4. **Restart Computer**
5. **Launch Without Debugging**
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
6. **Step Into Debugging**
   Hit <kbd>F11</kbd> to start debugging by stepping into the first line of executed code. If that works, the problem is likely in your code somewhere (possibly an *ehem* StackOverflow Exception)

   [image: Step Into]

   [image: Breakpoint on Application_Start]
7. **Break on CLR Exceptions**
   If there is a problem with the code on startup, you should break when thrown
   Go to Debug > Windows > Exception Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>)
   Select `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`

   [image: Exception Settings]

   [image: Common Language Runtime Exceptions]
8. **Change Project Port**
   Go to Project > Properties > Web > Project URL
   Try using **`8080`**, but any change might work

   [image: Web Settings > URL > Port]
9. **Create Virtual Directory**
   In the above screenshot, select `Create Virtual Directory` to the right of the Project Url
10. **Delete `.vs` folder**
    Open the Directory where the solution / project lives.
    Make sure *hidden* file are visible, and delete the `.vs` folder

    [image: Delete .vs folder]
11. **Restart IIS Express**
    In the system tray, right click on IIS Express and select Exit

    [image: Exit IIS Express]
12. **Enable 64 Bit IIS Express**
    ***If*** you're on a 64 bit machine...
    Go to Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Projects
    Select `Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express...`

    [image: Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express]
13. **Check Event Viewer**
    Check for any additional diagnostic information in Event Viewer under Windows Logs > Application

    [image: Event Viewer]

    [image: Windows Logs > Application > IIS Express]
14. **Run IIS Express from cmd line**
    You can rule out if there's an issue with Visual Studio or your Web Project itself.
    Here's the docs on [Running IIS Express from the Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line)
    Pass in the path to the root of your project (where the web.config) is located

    ```sh
    >  "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"  /path:C:\repos\project\
    ```
15. **Download IIS Express**
    Get the standalone installer for [Internet Information Services (IIS) 10.0 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264) and try again
16. **Disable Edit and Continue**
    Go to Project > Properties > Web > Debuggers
    Deselect `Enable Edit and Continue` although this will remove that functionality

    [image: Disable Edit and Continue]

#### Further Reading:

- [ASP.NET MVC5/IIS Express unable to debug - Code Not Running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19472682/1366033)
- [IIS Express crashes when starting a site from visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30406261/1366033)
- [Unable to launch IIS Express Web server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45480722/1366033)

Comment: I think deleting .vs was the solution in my case

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today. I had forgotten that I had set my application to a single instance application and I already was running another instance of the application in the background while I was trying to start another program instance.
To fix the problem you just have to open the program properties tab and uncheck the Make single instance application checkbox temporarily or close the same application running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

My situation was too interesting. I tried all solutions of KyleMit but it didnt work.
So when i looked back to my previous commits in one of my service method i saw an action like this :

```
  public List<Master> GetActiveMastersByCity(int cityId)
    {
        return GetActiveMastersByCity(cityId).Where(x => x.MasterStatus == MasterStatus.Active).ToList();           
    }
```

as you see there is a mistake in my method because in the scope the method name is wrong. it seems i tried call another method like GetAllActiveMastersByCity but i typed GetActiveMastersByCity is the same as my current method.

To be frank, this is too interesting adventure in my .net core story. Because its compiled and runned already and i did not understand absolutely why is this issue related with iis.

Hope it will helps you all.